# How to most easily run Google Play Game Services Examples downloaded from Github?

Tags: android, eclipse, github, google-play, google-play-games

I imported all the code from Github ([android-samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples)) as stated in [Google Play Game Services Downloads page](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/#samples).

My goal here to run the game "TypeANumber". When I import the code in eclipse, I see the following folder structure in picture below.
My question is - if I just want to run "TypeANumber" - what is the fastest way to do that? I dont want to create completely different project - copy the code there, make package name changes and then run the code - there has got to be a faster way, right?

[image]

Comment: Right click "Type A Number" and run

Comment: No luck, here's what i see when i do so: http://postimg.org/image/ybnu4k0rh/ & http://postimg.org/image/hnrlpt2bl/. Right-click > "run as" > "Run configuration" brings up this prompt: http://postimg.org/image/wrahx6489/

Comment: Are you in the Android perspective? Have you installed the SDK and the Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Yes, I have other Android app projects in the perspective running fine. Like in the screenshot, i am even running AndEngine samples and have some of own apps too. I have the SDK installed and running OK for other projects. Does this work simply by hitting run for you?

Comment: I am sorry I haven't tried running it (nor have I downloaded). I guess we should wait for a more experienced person to answer this

Comment: Try setting MainActivity as the activity to be run in Type A Number's settings

Answer (score 1):

Running the TypeANumber sample project requires several steps. Firstly, it should be linked with BaseGameUtils library project. Secondly, you must have Google Play Developer Console account because you have to setup a game service with required achievements and leaderboards. Also you must link that game service with your TypeANumber sample project.

You can find detailed instructions from the link below:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart

Good luck.